# read from .plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c

Got a little problem. I have a .plist file which contain next data [image: http://imageshack.com/a/img856/1421/xvzm.png]

So i cant understand, how i need read first array, than in array read dictionary. Or maybe need rewrite file and change Root key to type dictionary, and read like this:

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *plistPath;
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
}
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
    propertyListFromData:plistXML
    mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
    format:&format
    errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if (!temp) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
}
self.personName = [temp objectForKey:@"Name"];
self.phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"Phones"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by the following code:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray  *dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

This array will contain all the dictionaries, you can get them like:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Except this tosses out the code to load the file from the Documents folder if it exists.

Comment: And it doesn't actually answer the question. The question is about getting the desired data from the array.

Comment: `objectAtIndex:` is an old syntax, there's something newer

Comment: @IgorMatyushkin: `dataArray[0]`, I like the old syntax (don' know why :P)

Answer (score 1):

```
SString *plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];

for(NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
}

NSDictionary *item0 = array[0];
NSString *imageName = item[0][@"name"];
```

Comment: This tosses out the code to load the file from the Documents folder if it exists. The OP probably still wants that code.

Comment: The OP's code looks in the Documents folder first then uses the resource bundle as a fallback. For the OP's sake, I pointed out that this answer eliminates that logic.