# reading strings from the plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a `jobs.plist` file as you see in this image[image], which is saved in the Supporting Files directory of my xCode project

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722437/read-from-plist-file), in the viewDidLoad method of my viewController, I added this code to i) read in the file ii) store the contents of the file in an array (self.jobs), and then iii) get a random job from the array

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jobs" ofType:@"plist"];
NSLog(@"path %@", path);
self.jobs = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"jobs %lu", [self.jobs count]);
NSUInteger index = arc4random() % [self.jobs count];
NSLog(@"random job %@", [self.jobs objectAtIndex: index]);
```

When I run the code, however, the second log statement shows that there are `0` jobs (not the 6 that I expected) and the application freezes on the second to last line with an error

```
Thread 1:EXC_ARITHMETIC(code=exc_1386, div, subcode=0x)
```

Since the code is the same for reading in the plist file, I'm assuming I made a mistake with my plist. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: @rmaddy thanks that worked if you add an answer I'll accept it otherwise I'll add the answer later

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to read the plist as an array but it is defined as a dictionary.

Update your plist so the root's type is `array`.